# SQL query to convert columns into rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as shown below.My question is:How can I convert columns into rows?BTW,I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

my input Data

```
  ONAY_ID  sip_RECno    KULLANICI       ONAY
   1           1         user1          true
   2           1         user2          true
   3           1         user3          false
   4           1         user4          true
```

Output would be

```
 sip_RECno  user1     user2    user3     user4       

  1          true     true    false    true
```

Comment: What database/version are you working with? Based on previous questions, I'd assume SQL Server but you've had titles with 2000 and 2005 so version will matter

Comment: I've updated the tags to include [tag:sql-server] - can you please get in the habit of being specific (including version) so that folks using Oracle, DB2 etc. don't try to solve your problem with inappropriate solutions?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand-I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** for new data type revelation...

```
SELECT sip_RECno, 
    user1 = MAX(CASE WHEN ONAY_ID = 1 THEN CONVERT(TINYINT, ONAY) END),
    user2 = MAX(CASE WHEN ONAY_ID = 2 THEN CONVERT(TINYINT, ONAY) END),
    user3 = MAX(CASE WHEN ONAY_ID = 3 THEN CONVERT(TINYINT, ONAY) END),
    user4 = MAX(CASE WHEN ONAY_ID = 4 THEN CONVERT(TINYINT, ONAY) END)
FROM dbo.tablename
WHERE sup_RECno = 1
GROUP BY sip_RECno;
```